# Search MongoDB by closest region based on coordinates

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB to store about 1 million documents representing regions.

Each document contains a coordinates record in the following format

```
"coordinates" : {
    "longitude" : -77.02687,
    "latitude" : 38.888565
}
```

Given a set of coordinates `{ x, y }`, what query should I run to find the region ( document ) that is closest to it?

Comment: I think you need to query the dataset with a cursor with batches and check each one in your code

Comment: Use `$near` or `$geoNear`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MongoDB [geospatial-queries documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/geospatial-queries/) the answer is quite simple.

In order to query for locations near a region you should follow these steps

**Step 1**

Create an index on the location field

```
db.places.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )
```

**Step 2**

Find regions close to { -73.9667, 40.78 } ordered by closest locations

```
db.places.aggregate( [
   {
      $geoNear: {
         near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
         spherical: true,
         query: { category: "Parks" },
         distanceField: "calcDistance"
      }
   }
] )
```